# .NET Standard Pipeline: Error NETSDK1004 project.assets.json' not found. Nuget Restore

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, nuget

This is my first time working with pipelines. I have a library repo that is a `.NET Standard` library intended to be shared with others. I would like a pipeline that builds it and runs the unit test sln.

Currently I have this after selecting `ASP.NET` from the predefined options for configuring a pipeline.

```
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/MyLibrary.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '**\My.sln'
    vsVersion: '15.0'
    restoreNugetPackages: true

- task: VSTest@2 # NOT DONE YET
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
```

And I realize now that `restoreNugetPackages` is deprecated. But when I build I get the error `NETSDK1004 project.assets.json` not found which is related to not using restore.

When I select the predefined option for `restore`, I'm curious what feed should I be selecting from Azure Artifacts or should I be selecting my `nuget.config`. How would I build a `nuget.config`? I don't have one currently in the repo.

Below are my current NuGet packages for the sln if this helps

```
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces
NETStandard.Library
Newtonsoft.Json
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.uNSafe
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Add [NuGet task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to restore nuget packages before running the build:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
- task: VSBuild@1
```

Answer (score 0):

As similar pattern of Cace's answer, the below code resolved the problem in my environment.

azure-pipelines.yml:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```